# SQL Server 2005 edition for Web applications

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

We are developing a web application (ASP.NET) for a bank, and it uses SQL Server 2005. The bank will have to buy a license for SQL Server 2005.

The question is - **which SQL Server 2005 version / license** will be the **least expensive** for such purposes?

1) It seems that the SQL Server Express version which is totally free can do. However, it also seems that this version has limitations as to the exporting and importing of data, so this may be not the best choice.

2) There is a "**client access license**" (**CAL**) licencing model in SQL Server. In an ASP.NET application, it is possible to access data using the ASP.NET system user (although the web application may have hundreds or thousands of users). In this case, will it be enough to have an SQL Server license **for just 1 user** (the **ASP.NET system user** accessing the data)? If yes, this is probably the most cost-efficient solution.

Comment: What you are asking about are "Editions", not "versions". Developer Edition, Enterprise Edition, etc. are all editions.  SQL Server 2000, 2005, 2008 are all versions.

Answer (score 3):

1. SQL Server Express has some limitations but I don't know what you exactly mean by importing and exporting data. It does well for most small apps. I would consider the features I use in the application and the database size/CPU/memory requirement to see if SQL Server Express is applicable or not.
2. No, you can't use a single CAL for a [Web application](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/licensing-faq.aspx).

   > For externally focused server applications. Processor licensing is a better choice for externally focused server applications, **such as Internet and extranet scenarios**. It is often difficult to count devices or users in these scenarios, so hardware-based pricing is more straightforward.
   >
   > ---
   >
   > Also noted [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/e/6/1e68f92c-f334-4517-b610-e4dee946ef91/2008%20SQL%20Licensing%20Overview%20final.docx):
   >   Multiplexing: Use of Middleware, Transaction Servers, and Multitiered architectures
   >   Sometimes organizations develop network scenarios that use various forms of hardware and/or software that reduce the number of devices or users that directly access or use the software on a particular server, often called multiplexing or pooling hardware or software. Use of such multiplexing or pooling hardware and/or software does not reduce the number of CALs required to access or use SQL Server software. A CAL is required for each distinct device or user that is connected to the multiplexing or pooling software or hardware front end.

I suggest you consider [SQL Server 2008 Web Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/web.aspx)

Comment: Depends on the usage of the Application here.  Web Edition can only be used for public facing sites; not internal apps.

Comment: @DancesWithBamboo - why do you say that? The usage scenarios listed on the Web Edition page include "Intranet and Internet applications"

Comment: From MS SQL Server Site:
"SQL Server 2008 Web may be used only to support public and Internet accessible
    *      Web pages
    *      Web sites
    *      Web applications
    *      Web services

It may not be used to support line of business applications (e.g., Customer Relationship Management, Enterprise Resource Management and other similar applications)"

Comment: Intriguing, so it does. How to reconcile those two statements?

Comment: @Jeff: My interpretation is that it can be used for Internet and Intranet Web apps but not as the database server backend for CRM and ERP stuff. Basically, what matters is that the database is used as a "Web site" backend not as a business software backend (whether or not it's a Web app). That's a personal interpretation though.